# How should I choose the accents for Mahapps Metro

Tags: mahapps.metro

I am looking at creating custom Accents for the Mahapps Metro.  I see in the link [Creating Custom Accents and Themes](http://mahapps.com/guides/styles.html#custom) the following;

```
<!--ACCENT COLORS-->
<Color x:Key="HighlightColor">#FF9F0055</Color>

<!--80%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor">#CCD80073</Color>
<!--60%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor2">#99D80073</Color>
<!--40%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor3">#66D80073</Color>
<!--20%-->
<Color x:Key="AccentColor4">#33D80073</Color>
```

The AccentColor has a comment of 80%.  What does that mean?  80% of what?

Or for example if my HighlightColor is #FF004E9B what would be the 80% color of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the question the only thing I could find on this was [this answer on creating a full resource accent/color.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701013/how-to-create-mahapps-metro-accent-resource-from-specific-color)

In this example the only thing that is changed is the alpha channel of the ARGB.

```
Color.FromArgb((byte)(204), originalColor.R, originalColor.G, originalColor.B)
```

This would be the first accent Color or 80%.